# Ax on Azure- Connectivity with Local Clients

Tags: azure, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We want to deploy AX Dynamics on azure, we have created a DC/AX AOS/SQL VM's .

How does the local Pc/AX Clients of customers connect to azure DC VM?

Can I connect without creating a virtual network?

I need details on connectivity. 
I need 6 users to connect to AX on azure, what is the best way ?

Answer (score 3):

You connect to your Azure client using Remote Desktop.

You need an external IP-address for this.

There is a detailed instruction [here](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/microsoftdynamicsaxintegration/archive/2013/11/07/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-in-windows-azure-iaas-distributed-install.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to connect local clients to an Azure AOS, the latency will just be too high to be workable. 
Your performance will be terrible and users will complain about slowness.

The [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11094) say that you have to use Terminal Services when the latency is over 100ms, which it probably won't be, but in my experience it's just not workable.

The response time would be 
Response time = (Number of calls to and from the server * Latency) + Number of bytes sent/b

Which means that code doing 20 RPC calls (which isn't much in some situations) will already add 1.5 seconds to the response time. Add the database time and processing time to that and you'll soon be looking at every action taking seconds if not minutes.

Do as Jan suggested and get an extra remote desktop vm.